# Is accessing a double pointer array within a pointer array possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to pull off the statement where the error is occurring in the code below.

I'm getting a segmentation fault whenever this statement is executed.

Is there something wrong with this statement?

Suppose,

```
struct StructX
{
  int ** dblPtrArray;
}

int main()
{
  StructX * obj;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  obj[i].dblPtrArray[i][j] = 0;  // error here

return 0;
}
```

Comment: language? I assume C?

Comment: @bolov It's C++

Comment: please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: side note: this might be valid C++ syntax, but it's not C++. It's C. If you want to use C++ then properly use C++ with it's abstractions and standard library, i.e. `std::vector` in this case.

Comment: @bolov agreed, but I don't think `StructX * obj;` is valid C?

Comment: @George that was not my point

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with double pointer. You've basically got the following situation:

```
int* p;
*p = 24;
```

You access (dereference) an uninitialized pointer which is Undefined Behavior.

In your particular case `obj` is uninitialized and `obj[i]` is Undefined Behavior.

---

Aaaand here we go again: In C++ don't use raw pointers that denote ownership. Use smart pointers or in your case containers. In C++ don't use explicit calls of `new` and `delete`. Again use smart pointers if pointers with ownership is what you really need.

A fundamental concept in C++ is [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)